# bash цикл while

Tags: linux, bash

есть скрипт на bash который просит сначало вести имя и сколько лет, если от 1 до 15 то child, от 16 до 25 то youth, от 26 то adult если пустое имя или возраст 0 то должно писать bye и выходить, почему у меня скрипт не выполняется?

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 again=yes
  3 while [[ "$again" = "yes" ]]
  4 do
  5  echo "enter your name:"
  6  read name
  7  echo "enter your age:"
  8  read age
  9 if [[ 1  -le 15 ]]
 10   then
 11    echo "$name, your is child"
 12   elif [[ 16  -le 25 ]]
 13   then
 14    echo "$name, your is youth"
 15   elif [[ $# -ge 26 ]]
 16   then
 17    echo [[ "$name, your is adult" ]]
 18   else
 19    echo "bye"
 20 fi
 21 read again
 22 done
 23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрипт у вас выполняется, только цикл `while` не выполняется ни разу.

Во второй строке `yes` заключите в кавычки.

Кроме того, у вас неверно написаны условия сравнения и лишние скобки в строке 17. И выход не по условию

> если пустое имя или возраст 0

а если ввод `again` не равен `yes`.

Вот исправленный код:

```
#!/bin/bash

again="yes"
while [[ "$again" = "yes" ]]
do
  echo "enter your name:"
  read name
  echo "$name, enter your age:"
# UPD.1 ^^^^^ -- добавили обращение
  read age

  if [[ "$name" == "" ]]
  then
    again="no"
  else
    if [[  1 -le "$age" && "$age" -le 15 ]]
    then
      echo "$name, your is child"
    elif [[ 15 -lt "$age" && "$age" -le 25 ]]
    then
      echo "$name, your is youth"
    elif [[ "$age" -gt 25 ]]
    then
      echo [[ "$name, your is adult" ]]
    else
      again="no"
    fi
  fi

  if [[ "$again" = "no" ]]
  then
    echo "bye"
# UPD.2 -- удалили вопрос о продолжении работы
#  else
#    echo "continue?"
#    read again
  fi
done
```

Comment: Спасибо
а если нужно? что бы было
Elena
enter your age:
0
bye 

enter your name:
Elena Petrovna
enter your age:
25
Elena Petrovna, your group is youth
enter your name:

bye

Comment: @fermeg, из вашего комментария не понятно, что конкретно нужно получить? Обновил ответ, добавив обращение по введённому имени.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3815428/11.txt вот это

Comment: И вновь из документа по вашей ссылке ничего не понятно. Придётся догадываться. Вам не нужен вопрос пользователю продолжать или нет? Исправил код в ответе.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/11bqdplt29wsu2l/2222.txt?dl=0 так понятнее?)
Вам не нужен вопрос пользователю продолжать или нет? 
не нужен

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/Y2XSY1RkVZwwHd6Ec3xq3JfpXQGKfaZZt8BspDdPeqO4HwGSzVUQoI8apnV2vOGT/file